# When linking Firebase Analytics to Big Query, when is data exported?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I successfully managed to link Firebase Analytics with Big Query. I can see data in the Big Query web console, and create reports in Data Studio. However, I only see two exported tables at the moment:

[image]

So, there is data for the day after I linked Firebase analytics to Big Query (which was on 04/13), but then there is no data for 04/15, and no data after 04/16. There is analytics data for the missing dates which I can see in the Firebase analytics console.

When exactly is data from Firebase Analytics exported to Big Query? Are there any restrictions for the Firebase Big Query integration, that prevent data from being exported to Big Query? Anyone seeing similar behaviour?

Comment: i can not retrieve even data from firebase to big query, how you do it ? can you explain ? i have done linked apps to big query but the table only firebase_crashlytics and firebase_messaging not app_event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html) should help answer your question, but in general:

- When the Firebase Analytics servers receive your data from the device, they should be exporting that data almost immediately into an `app_events_intraday` table.
- At around midnight your time, the data gathered in your `app_events_intraday` table will be placed into a more permanent `app_events_<date>` table.

If you're not seeing this intraday table, and/or you're pretty sure you should have received some data from your clients on 4/15, I would file an issue at the Firebase [troubleshooting page](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/), since that doesn't sound right to me...

Comment: thanks Todd, interesting writeup in your blog post. I'll check again for the days missing in BigQuery, and eventually file an issue

Comment: Hi. How did you resolve it? I only see "Dataset not created" for Firebase Analytics in the settings. I cannot find any datasets in the BQ console either.